# How to detect "inner spin button" click with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page like this:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="2.50" step="0.50" id="myInput">

<script> 
         $('#myInput').on('input', function() {
           console.log($(this).attr('placeholder')); //prints 2.50 
         });
</script>
```

The `console.log` "works", but the problem is that I can't distinguish between a user pushing the "inner spin button" and manually entering a number.

Ultimately what I want to happen is when a user clicks the spin button, the input *value* becomes `3.00` (2.50 + 0.50), and when a user types a number manually, the value becomes whatever they typed.

Note that its really important that the value of the input is **not** set unless a user makes a change.

Any advice / other methods of doing this would really be appreciated :)

### Edit

Here's the scenario:
A business uses a page that has inputs generated like the one above, and multiple employees could potentially be on the same page at the same time.
Lets say employee A makes a change to the price of a product and leaves the page. Meanwhile, employee B is on the same page, which hasn't updated yet based on employee A's change, and saves the page.  This would revert all of employee A's changes on the page, hence why I am trying to avoid setting the value of the inputs on pageload.

Comment: I'd run that through a custom js function at that point, I don't think you can have it both ways if you define step, assuming the user input can be outside of the stepped values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set a `placeholder`... You also should set the starting `value`.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="2.50" step="0.50" value="2.50" id="myInput">
```

Then, when the user click the inner spins, it won't start from zero, but from that starting value.

And use the `change` event... Not the `input`, because it fires on each key entry.

Last... To force two decimals, the "trick" is to parse the `input` value, using [`.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and set the decimals with [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
var input_changed = false;

$('#myInput').on('change', function() {
  input_changed = true;
  $(this).val( parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2) )
});

$("#check").on("click",function(){
  if(!input_changed){
    console.log("0.00");
  }else{
    console.log( $('#myInput').val() );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" placeholder="2.50" step="0.50" value="2.50" id="myInput">

<button id="check">What the value? (like on submit)</button>
```

---

**EDIT**

> if I were able to increment the inputs by their placeholder...

Here is a solution where the input's value is not set on page load.

So if there is a placeholder, it is added to the value created by the user action. We have to clear that placeholder to avoid it being added more than once.

```js
$('#myInput').on('change', function() {
    value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    placeholder = parseFloat($(this).attr("placeholder")) || "";
    
    if(placeholder != ""){
        value = value + placeholder;
        $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
    }
    
    $(this).val( value.toFixed(2) )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" placeholder="2.50" step="0.50" id="myInput">
```

Or maybe you wish to **only use** the placeholder and never have a value?
Here the alternative:

```js
$('#myInput').on('change', function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var placeholder = parseFloat($(this).attr("placeholder")) || 0;
    var newPlaceholder = value + placeholder;
    
    $(this).attr("placeholder",newPlaceholder.toFixed(2) );
    $(this).val("").blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" placeholder="2.50" step="0.50" id="myInput">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am specifically trying to avoid setting the input value until a user manually changes it.

Comment: ok... I see. Then use a flage to know if the user changed it. The expected behavior of the spins requires the defined value... Let me edit. I have an idea.

Comment: I edited... But that question is getting to something else way more complex than just input formatting and behavior. You look for a real-time update here, as I understand it. And it is out of my current knowlege scope.

Comment: Sorry to throw that on you!  I was just trying to add context as to why I need this exactly, because if I were able to increment the inputs by their placeholder, the problem in the edit wouldn't exist.

Comment: Okay... I edited with some "alternatives"... See if that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Two `<input>s`

#### HTML

The following demo has an `<input type='text'>` to display the value and an `<input type='number'>` the size of a spinner that overlaps the other input. Since a `type="number"` doesn't display this format: `2.50` when using the spinner, a `type="text"` can but it'll take letters as well. To prevent input of letters, the attributes `[pattern]` and `[required]` are added. Those attributes only function upon a `submit` event. A `<form>` tag has been added since a `submit` event needs a `<form>` tag.

#### CSS

A `<fieldset>` is wrapped around all of the form controls and assigned `position: relative`. All of the form controls are assigned `position:absolute` and given `top` and `left` properties. The number input is assigned `z-index: 1` so it receives the user clicks. Note the dashed outline can be removed it's just there for demonstration purposes.

#### jQuery

When the `type="number"` is clicked, its initial value of `2.50` is converted to a real number then its applied to the `type="text"` input which in turn displays the value as a string in `n.nn` format.

---

### Demo

```js
$('#in1').on('click', function() {
  var base = parseFloat($(this).val());
  $('#in2').val(base.toFixed(2))
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#in1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  top: calc(50% - 0.75rem);
  left: 4.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

#in2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  top: calc(50% - 0.75rem);
  left: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font: inherit;
}

[type=submit] {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.35rem;
  height: 1.35rem;
  top: calc(50% - 0.75rem);
  left: 5.85rem;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <fieldset>
    <input id='in2' type='text' placeholder='2.50' pattern='[-0-9]+?|[-0-9]*?\.[0-9]+?' required autocomplete='off'>
    <input id='in1' type="number" value="2.50" step="0.50">
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```